# Angular 4, How to update [(ngModel)] with a delay of 1 seconds

Tags: angular, ngmodel

Since ngModel is updating instantly how to put a delay.

```
  <input type="text" value="{{item.task_name}}" name="task_name" [(ngModel)]="item.task_name" (ngModelChange)="update_fields([item.task_name])" >
```

I need to save the task_name with a delay of one seconds by calling update_fields() , To avoid instant calls to service.

Thanks

Comment: add delay to your service instead

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Rxjs** and **Observables** are the perfect candidate for this type of task! Here is an example of how it can be achieved:

**Template:**

```
<input type="text" [value]="item.task_name"(keyup)="term$.next($event.target.value)">
```

**Component:**

```
import ......

import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component{(
  ...
)}
export class YourComponent {

  term$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
    this.term$
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => /*do something*/);
  }
}
```

`subject` is a type of object that acts both as an observable and observer - meaning you can both subscribe to it and emit values from it (with `next()`)!

`debounceTime` waits for the provided time in ms until it allows for new changes

`distinctUntilChanges` will not allow the same input to pass through two times in a row

`switchMap` takes the latest observable from the chain so you don't get multiple results at once

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner, can you please update the import part also, Becoz "Cannot find name subject" error is showing,Even I added -- import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";  also

Comment: @JomyJoseph added imports to my answer :)

Comment: I just used `subscribe` instead of `switchMap` and it worked.

Comment: Not sure if it's how I'm using it, however I'm finding the switchMap function (Angular5) requires a return. So return Observable.empty() - or whatever for instance.

Answer (score 14):

Answer by Fredrik Lundin updated for Angular 6:

**Template:**

```
<input type="text" [value]="item.task_name" (keyup)="term$.next($event.target.value)">
```

**Component:**

```
import ......

import { Subject, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component{(
  ...
)}
export class YourComponent implements OnDestroy {

  term$ = new Subject<string>();

  private searchSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {
    this.searchSubscription = this.term$.pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => {
        /*do something*/
        return EMPTY;
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    //remember to unsubscribe on destroy

    if (this.searchSubscription) {
      this.searchSubscription.unsubscribe();
      this.searchSubscription = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a great example that i am using, but the pipe doesn't have .'s in front of the functions, they need to be comma separated.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: @vangras can you maybe explain what's different or better about your solution compared to Fredrik's?

Answer (score 3):

Lots of solutions using `setTimeout()`, but this will cause the function to be called each time the model changes, a simple way to prevent this is to clear the timeout first

e.g.

```
timeOut;
timeOutDuration = 1000;

update_fields(data) {
  clearTimeout(this.timeOut);
  this.timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
     //do something
  }, this.timeOutDuration);
}
```

this will only call the function once after the last update is made and the `timeOutDuration` has elapsed

Answer (score 0):

```
update_fields(){

  this.service.yourTask(){
    .subscribe(data => {
      setTimeout(()=>{ //your task }, 4000)
    }    
  }
}


someFunction() {
    setTimeout(() => /* code to execute */, 3000)
}
```

Comment: If i type "xyz"  with in 1 seconds. whether it will call three times with a delay 1 sec ?

Comment: Yes it should you can try